# /var got mysteriously renamed in /var.1 on CentOS6 server

Tags: server, centos

On one of our CentOS6 servers, /var got renamed to /var.1 tonight (around 3.24 am) and a new empty /var folder was created. Not surprisingly, it crashed soon after that.

Circumstances:

- Over the last two days, we have been DDOS'd by botnet activity conducting an apparent reflection attack against a large local business
- This (mail, name) server exposes imap(s) pop3(s) smtp(s), http(s) and 587 ports - all of them FortiGate and fail2ban protected. All experienced unusual activity related to the previous point.
- The time of the accident is about the same of the standard cron maintenance activity

I am still poring over the logs. Because of the first point, malware would be an obvious suspect **except** that renaming /var is a pretty self-harming activity for some actor willing to take over the machine while concealing itself. So I am thinking at some maintenance task gone awry (such as a disk filling up during /var cleanup). However, I cannot think of anything that does similar shenanigans.

Is anybody able to shed light?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some log perusal, it turns out no foul play was involved. Somebody made an editing snafu in a logrotate config file, about 15 days ago, for a monthly rotation 
( var log /stuff instead of /var/log/stuff). As luck had it, it kicked in during the DDOS, clouding the picture - though, in truth, the var**.1** thing should have given me pause much sooner. Thanks to all who bothered.